# In Django how to stop a signal running during migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Is there a way in Django to stop a `post_save` signal from firing during the migration commands?

I have a `post_save` signal which runs on all models, however I've found that during migrations it runs, although Django seems to deal with this problem with a warning. I'm wondering if there is a best practice I've missed?

```
@receiver(post_save)
def action_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Action.objects.update_action(instance)
       # Edited for brevity
```

I have seen [Disconnecting signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals) however this is going to be removed in 1.9 so is there a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Signal.disconnect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals) sounds like the correct approach. It is not being removed in Django 1.9. The docs just say that the `weak` argument is being deprecated as it had not effect.

Comment: I misread the docs thanks. it did seem a bit strange and not very clear (to me anyway).